# Script via SSH Hang forever

Tags: bash, ssh

I have this simple script file called `aaaa.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
main(){
echo 'aaaaa'
more aaaa.sh
echo 'bbbb'
}
main
```

when I run this script from local its run with no problem but when I run it on the same machine remotely via ssh

```
ssh user@host './aaaa.sh'
```

it's stack forever after printing aaaaa

any idea?

Comment: Your SSH probably doesn't allocate a TTY. Try with `ssh -t`

Comment: As tripleee implied, the `more` command expects user input from a TTY terminal. But when you run `ssh user@example 'commands'`, it runs in non-interactive mode (no TTY terminal is allocated).